# in rendering plugin external font imported by css is not working when download pdf

Tags: css, grails, rendering, gsp

I am trying to download my gsp page as pdf using rendering plugin in grails. I want to import my own font in pdf. I am using css for import font-face.

```
@font-face {
    src: url('Philosopher.otf');
    -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
    -fs-pdf-font-encoding: cp1250;
    font-family: philosopher;
}
body {
        font-family: "Philosopher";
    }
```

I am writing it in print media. when I open it browser its working fine. but when I try to download pdf ,my font is not shown in pdf. pdf show me its default font. Is there any other way to show my font in pdf except css, because css for font is not working for me.

Comment: Yes there is an undesired way. Show your static content rendered as image in PDF.

Comment: I do not get what you exactly want to say? can you please elaborate?

Comment: For example, "My name is Vivek Yadav". Create an image of this text with your font and use that image in PDF. That is why I said an undesired way.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I am using dynamic value in gsp page not static. 
So I can not use image of my text. Is there any other way in mind please tell.

Comment: Have you placed your font in web-app as a static resource?

Comment: yes. my font is in web-app and I am providing exact path for that font, as I write in my post.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31118/discussion-between-dmahapatro-and-vivek-yadav)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I resolved by using absolute url in the css link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${grailsApplication.config.grails.serverURL}/css/pdf.css" media="all" />
```

and I also excluded CSS and all used resources from the resource plugin:

```
grails.resources.adhoc.excludes = ['/css/pdf.css','/images/background.png', '/css/SectionUnicode.ttf']
```

Comment: is this sufficient to add my own font in pdf using css via rendering plugin.

Comment: Sorry, no. I forgot to say that I also excluded the CSS and the font from the resource plugin.